# asp.net forms authentication - make a folder publicly available

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication in a MVC 2 project.

I have this in my web.config:

```
 <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

I want the /Content folder to be available to users that haven't been authenticated yet. The login view uses the css in that folder, which should be available at login time.

Thanks

Comment: Im sorry and am not too familiar with MVC but have a decent amount of experience with forms authentication. Is this config file in your project root or in your /Content folder? You can have a web.config in each with different permissions. If you go into the .NET config security settings through VS and use that tool to set these rules it will automatically create them for you. Or you can define everything in your main web.config by using locations like my example below.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. So far, my app had one web.config file in the root folder and one in the \Views folder (default mvc project). The file I mentioned on my question was on the root folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the css file as a location in your config file like this:

```
<location path="whatever.css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This would be external of your main system.web block i believe

if this content folder is a separate folder it can have its own web.config file that you can set to allow=*

Comment: Thanks!, I added a new Web.config file inside the /Content folder with <allow users="*"/>

Answer (score 0):

do you mean:

```
 <authorization>
     <allow users="*" />
 </authorization>
```

Comment: No, it is like I posted it on the question.

Comment: sorry, I should have explained more...that was the declaration I was wanting you to try...